# Android studio apk analyzer only decompiling one DEX file

Tags: java, android-studio, apk, dex, smali

I'm aware of how APK's are formatted and how DEX files have a 64kb limit, and beyond 64kb you need to multidex. Could this be why android studio apk analyzer only decompiles one DEX file? Am I missing something somewhere?

Comment: AS APK Analyzer decompiles all the dex files on v3.4.1 (at least on my machine). Which version do you use? Have you tried with different APKs? What exactly is your experience?

Comment: My AS version is 3.4.2. I fixed my problem by decompliling the application with apktool and then just opening the output folder in AS. I could then set break points in the smali code whilst I run a vm with the same application with debug enabled. I also tried a few other applications just to sanity check the situation. Still a no go. Applications: Instagram, Facebook, Twitter, snapchat. Not an issue anymore, but in the future it would be nice to just open the application inside of AS and not have to use a 3rd party application. Any advice?